# Is there a way to use a range of values to populate a dropdown list and then delete those values outside of the list?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where I've entered a bunch of values individually, but I'd like to take the values in each row and put them into a single dropdown list instead. I could manually enter options, but in some cases, the number of options is very large, so I figure creating a dropdown from a range is the way to go. However, once the values are in the dropdown list, I no longer need the cells with the individual entries. But if I've made a dropdown list from a range rather than manually, it seems the options are continually linked to the cells they're sourced from. In other words if I delete the row, the dropdown list empties as well. Is this a limitation of google sheets or is there a method I'm overlooking?

I'm not very knowledgable about formulas and it's been a hard question to google, so the only thing I've tried is messing with the different "paste special" options, none of which seem to do what I want (retain the list but keep the values rather than the references within each option in the list).

Answer (score 0):

*For this example solution, let’s assume you’ve already gathered all the values you want into your drop-down into the range `A2:A900`.*

*Anywhere you see `A2:A900` below just replace with where your values are.*

1. In `B2` enter `=TEXTJOIN(“,”,TRUE, A2:A900)`.
2. Right click on `B2` then click “Copy”.
3. Right click on `C2` then click “Paste special, values only”
4. Right click on `C2` then click “Copy”.
5. Go to the cell where you want the drop-down menu.
6. Right click on that sell, hover on “more” at the bottom, then “Data Validation”. ***Note**: if you previously had a drop-down here already you may want to click remove validation before adding a new one.*
7. Instead of “from range” **choose “from list”** and paste your already comma-separated values into the field.
8. Go back and delete ‘A2:C900` and confirm that the drop-down values are still in the drop-down.

Comment: @Ralon17 did the suggestion above solve your issue?